# One PC saying "Limited Connectivity", others working just fine

Tags: windows-7, networking, wired-networking, windows-networking

I have 2 PCs. One is a desktop with Windows 7, the other is a laptop with Windows 10. The windows 10 laptops connects fine. The windows 7 desktop says that the connection is limited. It is connected to the router with an Ethernet cable. I have tried running the Windows Network Troubleshooter, which says it cannot detect the problem. I have also tried disabling the network adapter and enabling it again. Finally, I have rebooted many times. What is causing this issue and how do I fix it?

**IPCONFIG for Windows 10 machine** 
http://pastebin.com/iXYD1bBK 
**IPCONFIG for Windows 7 machine** 
http://pastebin.com/nsXf3FTa

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the output of `ipconfig /all` from both machines?

Comment: Added IPCONFIG ouputs to questiosn

Comment: Thanks, that makes the problem pretty obvious... Answer coming shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DHCP is not enabled and you have no Default Gateway defined, thus your PC cannot connect outside of your own subnet and it cannot access the Internet.

If you are using a static IP address, you must have IP address, subnet mask, default gateway, and DNS servers defined. In your Win7 machine, according to your ipconfig output, you have no default gateway defined, setting that to 192.168.1.1 should correct the issue and allow connectivity.

The alternative if a static IP address is not needed is to change the IPv4 settings to Obtain Automatically for both IP information and DNS information.

Once this is complete, open a command window as Administrator and enter `netsh int ip reset` and reboot, then try to access the internet again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that did not fix the issue. It is still says limited internet access. New IPCONFIG:  http://pastebin.com/jH6ecGaz

Comment: @Jackpen7 Note line 64... `DHCP Enabled: No`... you need to enable DHCP

Comment: How do I enable DHCP?

Comment: @Jackpen7 Try http://www.ghacks.net/2015/08/17/fix-dhcp-is-not-enabled-for-local-area-connection/

Comment: DHCP is now enabled. It is still saying limited access. New IPCONFIG http://pastebin.com/7smEpDQt

Comment: @Jackpen7 OK, I'm going to backup a bit... Which adapter are you connecting to, you appear to have 2 or 3 Ethernet adapters, do you have connectivity (lights) on either the end? Have you tried one of the alternate ports? Your ipconfig output appears like there is no media connected...

Comment: I am trying to connect the `Killer e2200 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller`  There is one green light on the Killer port and one amber light on the router port. And yes I have two LAN ports and 1 wireless card. I have tried the other LAN port and WiFi and have the same error.

Comment: @Jackpen7 Do you have a Bootable Linux flash drive, like newer Mint or Ubuntu? At this point I believe hardware needs to ruled out, booting to an alternative OS temporarily could save lots of troubleshooting. Also, has this ever worked, of so what changed?

Comment: I do not have a Linux flashdrive but could make one. I have not changed anything. My PC had been working yesterday. I shut it down last night, and this morning after I turned it on I started having this issue

Answer (score 0):

It could possibly be caused by a bad network adapter, a bad driver or a bad ethernet cable. You can try setting a static ip on the windows 7 computer.

Comment: I set up a static IP and that did not fix the problem. The PC also says limited network access when I connect via WiFi. How would I go about fixing a bad driver?

Comment: Check on the manufacturer page. There should be a up to date driver.

Answer (score 0):

Check the windows 7 machine if the TCP/IPv4 or TCP/IPv6 is set to obtain ip address automatically. [Win7 Connection Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smv4f.jpg)